# Using 'disallow results from triggers' in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, triggers, azure-sql-server

The use of the sp_configure function is not supported in Azure, however, I am looking to use the following:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE 
EXEC sp_configure 'disallow results from triggers', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

However, it is unclear how to do this.

See this article for more details on the setting:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/disallow-results-from-triggers-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15

Edit
Running the following in Azure shows the state as 0:

```
SELECT value
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'disallow results from triggers'
```

To clarify I just want triggers that don't return a count, so using SET NOCOUNT ON at the start of the trigger and then SET NOCOUNT OFF at the end. The trigger itself is just INSERTing some audit data.

Setting the disallow results from triggers option throws a warning because of the NOCOUNT.

Comment: If you're using Azure why have you tagged SQL Server 2008 as well; which isn't available in Azure as it hasn't been supported for almost *3 years*.

Comment: Personally, however, I would suggest you fix your triggers. Returning a dataset from a trigger is deprecated, and shouldn't be done. If you *do* have triggers than return datasets, then fix them; don't force the end user to get an error because someone has written a bad trigger.

Comment: Pretty sure this is how this is already set in Azure SQL Database. Are you actually trying to turn the configuration option _off_ (e.g. you have triggers you _need_ to get results from)?

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the incorrect tag and added more info. The trigger itself does not return a result, but will return a records affected count which I didn't want.
I am trying to enable the configuration option.